# Check if a word in a sentence is alphanumeric and return the alnum word

Tags: regex, python-3.x, alphanumeric

I've been working on a project and I've to check if the strings entered by user are alphanumeric or not.
For now, I've built my code and there's one function which needs to check if any word is alphanumeric or not.
The program is to let user enter a sentence along with his license number which would be alphanumeric like '221XBCS'. So, if the user enter suppose- 'My license number is 221124521' instead of 221XBCS I want the program to stop.
But my current program is assuming the re.match condition is true always. WHY IS IT SO??

```
import re
s = input("Please enter here:")

if re.search(r'\bnumber \b',s):
            x = (s.split('number ')[1])
            y = x.split()
            z = y[0]
            print(z)
            if re.match('^[\w-]+$', z):
                print('true')
            else:
                print('False')
```

The output looks like this for now:

```
Please enter here:my license number is 221
is
true
```

I want my program to grab alnum value from the input. That's all!

Comment: Look, `is` is matched with `^[\w-]+$`. Hence, it is true. If you need to check if the input is alphanumeric, you can also use `isalnum()`. But I see you also need to support a hyphen, so why not use `if re.search(r"\bnumber\s+([\w-]+)", s)`, and if it matches, grab the `group(1)` value?

Comment: Even if I give the input - 'my license number 22184849' it is still true for the condition. If I use 're.search(r"\bnumber\s+([\w-]+)", s)' II get AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @TarakShah, elaborate your conditions: is the word `number` mandatory?

Comment: P.S. I'm new to regex. :D

Comment: No @RomanPerekhrest words are not mandatory. I want that the user enters his/her license number which is alphanumeric

Comment: @TarakShah, Also, *to grab alnum value* means to extract alnum number, but for your case - it's enough to detect the occurrence without extracting ... or what?

Comment: No. I want to pass this anlum value to another funtions...to categorize them for my application

Comment: Ok.... Try `m = re.search(r'\b(?=\w*\d)(?=\w*[a-zA-Z])\w+',s)`. If m is not None, pass it to any function. Replace `\w` with `[\w-]` if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understood your condition: the user should enter his license number which should contain only alphabetic characters **AND** numbers (both):

With built-in functions:

```
s = input("Please enter here:")
l_numbers = list(filter(lambda w: not w.isdigit() and not w.isalpha() and w.isalnum(), s.strip().split()))
l_number = l_numbers[0] if l_numbers else ''

print(l_number)
```

---

Let's say the user entered `My license number is 221XBCS thanks.`
The output will be:

```
221XBCS
```

Answer (score 0):

With regular expressions, it is often valuable to look at the problem the reverse way.
It is, in this case, better to look if the string is NOT a pure numerical than looking if it IS an alphanumerical.

```
        if re.match('[^\d]', z):
            print('The string is no a pure numerical')
```

Comment: Not working for me. I want the code to detect an alnum value of his/her license which looks like this '221xncnd22' Now, using re.match('[^\d]', z) I'm getting Please enter here:my license number is 221xx
The string is no a pure numerical for any input

Comment: If you want to detect something NOT in a sentence, try to match the spaces.

If you want to detect a license number inside a sentence, try to detect a fixed digit number, here 8 alanum chars :

     /(^| )([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})( |$)/